# Error after adding reference to my project(TlGallioAddOn.dll)

Tags: c#, testing

I have added the reference TlGallioAddOn.dll to our sample c# application. I have using that reference like `using TlGallioAddOn;`. When using that reference of that dll it shows the following error.

```
The type or namespace name 'TlGallioAddOn' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Could u all please help me to resolve that.

Comment: is CopyLocal property of the reference set to True?

Comment: No we are not setting any property.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project in your Solution Explorer. Click 'Add Reference' then find your DLL.  It will import the DLL and resolve the error.

Comment: S we have added reference by right click and then add reference.

Comment: So it does show up in Source\<application sample project>\References\TlGallioAddOn ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the framework target of both projects.

Project defaults are now .NET 4.0 Client. If you've compiled the addon project against .NET 4.0 (Full), you'll need to modify the project for which you're adding a reference to use .NET 4.0 (Full) also.

Comment: Are you able to double-click the reference and open your addon in Object Explorer?  If so, verify the namespace of the type you're trying to include with the using directive. e.g. did you forget a namespace block around the type, is the namespace spelled differently, etc.

Comment: Have been able to open that reference using NUnit. But in our application we have used mbunit.